# Deleting an entire line and line breaks

Tags: python, python-3.x

i'm relatively new to Python, and i'm currently having some trouble running a script. I need a script that deletes every line that starts with an specific character (in this case is ">") and deletes all line breaks, joining the text file in one single line, except for the first line starting with ">" in the file, that must remain intact. what i've got so far is this

```
import sys
import os
import fileinput

x = open('seq.fasta','r')
y = open('seq.fasta.tmp', 'w')
text = ''
for line in x:
    if '>' in line:
        text += line
    else:
    text += line.replace("\n","")
y.write(text)
x.close()
y.close()
```

It reads the document, skips the line with the ">" (so it does not delete the linebreak on the first line), and deletes all line breaks. What i'm missing is the line delete part.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Both parts of your `if` statement add the line into `text`; you need to determine when the line should *not* be added, and then don't.